# "I made a list. Let's take a look." or "I made a list. Let's have a look."

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, difference

I have a question.

> "I made a list. Let's take a look."
>   or
>
> "I made a list. Let's have a look."

Which way is correct ?
What's the difference between these sentences ?

Answer (score 1):

'Take' is typical of American English, and 'have' is typical of British English, if I'm not mistaken. [Here's a reference to a similar discussion on here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/have-a-look-vs-take-a-look)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Can you provide some references to back-up your answer? See [answer] for more.

Answer (score 0):

There's no semantic difference between the phrases "to have a look" and "to take a look".  However, in BrE, you usually say:

I've made a list.  Let's have a look (at it).

In AmE, you usually say:

I made/have made a list. Let's take a look (at it).